# resize input field size in New Form (Calendar - SP2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, css

I like to set up a calendar for users to input some information.
By default the form looks OK but some fields are just way too long.

I am trying to resize the input field but can't get it to work.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<script>td.ms-long { width: 150px !important; }</script>

<script>.ms-long { width: 150px !important; }</script>
```

Here is the css from the FireBug

[image]

Please advise

PS: I am not really great in coding :/

Comment: Thank you both worked perfectly and it is good to know that you can change all of the fields or specific ones. I appreciate the sharing of knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<style>
    td.ms-long { width: 150px !important; }
</style>
```

Instead of

```
<script>
    td.ms-long { width: 150px !important; }
</script>
```

It should be `<style>`, not `<script>`. Current code will adjust all the field which are present in `<td>` with class `ms-long`

For particular department field:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[title="Department"]').css('width','150px');

  });

</script>
```

Don't forget to add JQuery reference.

**Edit:**

What I have did, I have downloaded the jquery file and uploaded into site asset, and given the reference link of jquery from site assets. Other than this I have written the same code which I have specified here. Also I have removed '! important', it was not working. Try clearing the browser cache too

You can also use ID of the control:

```
$('#YourControlID').css('width','150px');
```

Comment: yeh I just noticed that lol will your code adjust all the other fields or only the Department field ?! would be great if I can specify which ones to resize or not.

Comment: the particular code seems not to be working, although I added the JQuery reference as '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'

Comment: Let me verify at my end

Comment: Just surround the code with $(document).ready() function. Its working. Silly mistake of not putting $(document).ready()

Comment: still not working over here ... I tried with a script editor and also via the Content Editor.  None of them work :( what am I missing!!

Comment: What I have did, I have downloaded the jquery file and uploaded into site asset, and given the reference link of jquery from site assets. Other than this I have written the same code which I have specified here. Also I have removed '! important', it was not working. Try clearing the browser cache too

Comment: yes that is what I have done as well and cleared the cache too. If I change it back to `td.ms-long { width: 150px !important; }` the fields get resized right away without deleting the cache. By the way I am on IE 11.447

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50021/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-bucki).

Comment: in my case I had to use the #ID instead `$('#ID').css('width','150px');` thanks to Trimanta Software support

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-long {
width: 150px !important;
}
</style>
```

Insert in a content editor/script editor web part on the same page the form is.

Comment: ahhh silly me, I was using <script> instead :( damn!!

Comment: by the way, what would I have to add if I wanted only one specific field such as the Department field?!

Comment: @Bucki, Trimantra got the second part right about how to change a specific fields width.